# PostgreSQL Connection issues- Python

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

i want to connect a python code with a database localized in a Google Cloud Platform PostgreSQL database. I've been running this code and this working correctly, but recently i chaged me server to a VPS provided by a host. Now when i try to connect to the database with python3 i receive the follow message:

```
Psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "35.199.90.49" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have authorized the IP of the server in the Google Cloud Platform, i tried to open all IPv4 address too, but nothing is working. I changed the /XX from IPv4 for my server. I disabled the firewall of the server. Nothing is working but when i connect with the psql command at ubuntu server, the database connection is okay.

Comment: Have you double-checked the IP address?  Did you move the database, or just the code?

Comment: I keep the database at google cloud and i opened the connection for the IP Addr of the server, the problemn is when a try to connect with python. If i connect to the database with de psql ubuntu command line, the connection work normaly.

Comment: To your question add  1) The Python code that is actually making the connection. 2) The `psql` connection string. 3) Are you connecting from the same client machine when using the Python  code as when you do the `psql` connection?

Comment: Its not a specific code of python, all connections i want do with the database in python are showing the same issue, the connection string is correctly, i've tried the same string in another 2 servers and in my machine, the code runned correctly. And yes, i'm connecting psql with the same machine i've tried to connect with the python codes. I think i have found the issue, i will try to redo the network config. I will try remove the /XX from the gateway in yaml and wait propagation of the connection changes.